# SummaryWriter not writing summaries to file

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to use tensorflow's SummaryWriter, however it does not seem to write events, images, or histograms to file. However it does write the graph to file, (which I can then see in tensorboard), indicating at least, tensorboard and SummaryWriter know where my logdir is.

Here is my (simplified) code, broken up by omitted code blocks:

```
sess = tf.Session()
W_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5,5,3, hidden1_size], stddev = 0.01), name = 'W_conv1')
b_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape=[hidden1_size]), name = 'b_conv1')

#to visualize the weights of the first layer...
sum2 = tf.image_summary('first layer weights', tf.transpose(W_conv1, perm = [3, 0, 1, 2]), max_images = 16)

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(b_conv1 + conv(x, W_conv1))

#to visualize how many dead relu's we have
sum1 = tf.scalar_summary('conv1', tf.nn.zero_fraction(h_conv1))
```

.... More layers

```
softmax = {}
cross_entropy = tf.Variable(0.0)
softmax[0] = tf.nn.softmax(fc_out)
cross_entropy += -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(softmax[0]))
```

.... Reccurrent Part

```
sum3 = tf.histogram_summary('cross entropy', cross_entropy)


lr = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1e-3))
lr_change = tf.assign(lr, tf.mul(.1, lr))

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(cross_entropy)

merged=tf.merge_all_summaries()
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("./logs", sess.graph_def, flush_secs = 5)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

.... and then the training code:

```
for i in range(train_iter):
    batch_i = np.random.randint(0, len(X_t), [batch_size])
    X_batch = X_t[batch_i]
    y_batch = y_t[batch_i]

    summary_str, _, loss = sess.run([merged, train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict = {x: X_batch, y_: y_batch}) 

    writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
    writer.flush()
    saver.save(sess, 'RNN_model.ckpt', global_step = i)
```

Then when I load tensorboard, and look at the events tab, I see the following error:

> No scalar summary tags were found.
>
> Maybe data hasn't loaded yet, or maybe you need to add some >tf.scalar_summary ops to your graph, and serialize them using the >tf.training.summary_io.SummaryWriter.

I added the writer.flush() statement, because after searching on both stack exchange on github, that's a common suggestion. Issue not fixed.

In my logs file, only the graph_def is written, no other files are written during training.

I'm using tensorflow '0.7.1' on mac 0SX el-capitan.

Thanks!

Comment: Your TensorBoard /summary usage looks correct.
Are you sure that only the graph_def is being written to the events file? Can you upload it? Then I can check whether it has the histogram summaries, etc written and determine if the issue is with TensorBoard or the event-writing code.

Comment: Sure, thanks so much! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5GqMWTiEZZAR2gyU3RiWDFzMVE/view?usp=sharing
p.s. I think it's only the graph bc. it only write the file once when I define the network, but never during training.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing by running the example Docker experiment from [openai/InfoGAN](https://github.com/openai/InfoGAN#running-experiment).

It only output a log when at the start, but output nothing after training.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I was experiencing the same thing in a virtual environment running TensorFlow 1.1.0.  Running version 1.2.1 I don't seem to have this problem.  You can execute the following at the command line to determine which version of TensorFlow you're running:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"
```

Hope it helps someone out there!

Cheers,

-Maashu